# Get Content Of Wikipedia Page to Android

Tags: java, android, json, wikipedia

I have an android app that gets info about some topic from wikipedia and shows the info in a Toast..
I get the info using an API request using the URL :
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=chocolate
where chocolate is the search keyword or the topic which the user searches for...

I get that info in java using JSON :

```
    final String QUERY = "query";
    final String LIST = "search";
    final String TITLE = "title";
    final String SNIPPET = "snippet";

    JSONObject searchJson = new JSONObject(searchJsonStr);
    JSONObject queryObject = searchJson.getJSONObject(QUERY);
    JSONArray searchObject = queryObject.getJSONArray(LIST);
    JSONObject titObject = (JSONObject) searchObject.get(0);

    String title = titObject.getString(TITLE);
    String description = titObject.getString(SNIPPET);
```

The title variable returns the value : Chocolate which is the right thing..
but description returns :
 "For other uses, see Chocolate (disambiguation).       Chocolate i/\u02c8t\u0283\u0252k(\u0259)l\u0259t/ is a typically sweet, usually brown, food preparation of Theobroma cacao"

I don't need that  tags and class and so.. I just want it to be like this..
"Chocolate is a typically sweet, usually brown, food preparation of Theobroma cacao"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want decode string, just decode string using method:

```
private static String decode(String myString) {
    byte[] utf8Bytes = null;
    String convertedString = null;
    try {
        utf8Bytes = myString.getBytes("UTF8");
        convertedString = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF8");
        return convertedString;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

You will see string "Chocolate i/ˈtʃɒk(ə)lət/  is a typically sweet, usually brown"

**UPD:** /ˈtʃɒk(ə)lət/ - is a transcription of word

Comment: I tried this.. <span> tags still visible.. Thanks for your help

Comment: @MuhammadAshraf if you want to cut all html tags, you should write regexp